# Verifying MD5 passwords using password_verify()

Tags: php, hash, passwords, php-password-hash

Is there a way to convert a `MD5` password to something that can be verified by `password_verify()`?

I read on the [Crypt Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)#MD5-based_scheme) that "The printable form of `MD5` password hashes starts with `$1$`."

Hence I give this a shot (without any luck):

```
$password = "abcd1234";
$md5hash = "$1$".md5($password);
var_dump(password_verify($password, $md5hash));
```

Is there any way to make `password_verify()` work with `MD5` passwords?

Reason for question: I have an old system where the passwords are stored as `MD5` hashes. I want to start using the more secure [`Password Hashing API`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php). If I'm able to convert the existing password hashes to something that works with `password_verify()`, I can just update the database entries (prepend `$1$` to all password hashes), and my program would work beautifully using the following code (I don't have to make a special case for the old `MD5` passwords):

```
$password; // Provided by user when trying to log in
$hash; // Loaded from database based on username provided by user
if(password_verify($password, $hash)) {
   // The following lines will both update the MD5 passwords
   // and all passwords whenever the default hashing algorithm is updated
   if(password_needs_rehash($hash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)) {
      $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
      // Store the new hash in database
   }
   // User is logged in
} else {
   // User is not logged in
}
```

Comment: I think you should append the `$1$` to `$md5hash` and don't hash `$password`.

Comment: md5 hashes are supposedly one way - that is the point of a hash. However, md5 is broken and there are sites out there that have huge dictionaries of broken md5 hashes - you might be able to convert the passwords by looking them up in their databases? Have a gander at http://md5.wisetock.com/11347

Comment: The best way would be to get your user to change their password.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your first comment, @frz3993. `$1$` _is_ part of `$md5hash`, and when should `$password` not be hashed? Prompting the users to change their passwords is not a good option for me. If I don't find a solution to the question, I'll make a special case in which `$hash` is compared to `md5($password)` instead of using `password_verify()` when `$hash` does not start with `$`.

Comment: @RamRaider I don't think converting the md5 hashes to passwords for rehashing is a good solution, as different passwords can result in the same md5 hash. If I rehash a different password than the password the user is using, the rehash will not work with the user's password, even if both passwords give the same md5 hash.

Comment: I agree @Magnar Myrtveit

Comment: @RamRaider, `password_verify()` compare bare password with the hash, not compare hashes. Why not if hash does not start with `$` compare with `md5($password)` if successful `password_hash` the `$password` and update it in db.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that.

What you can do is to hash the *already MD5-hashed* passwords via `password_hash()` and put an additional flag for these old passwords in your database, so you know to double-verify them afterwards.

Some sample code:

```
$passwordCompare = ($passwordIsOldFlag === true)
    ? md5($passwordInput)
    : $passwordInput;

if (password_verify($passwordCompare, $passwordHash))
{
    if ($passwordisOldFlag === true)
    {
        $passwordNewHash = password_hash($passwordInput, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        // Here, you'd update the database with the new, purely bcrypt hash
        // and set your passwordIsOldFlag to 0 as well
    }
}
```

Note: MD5 produces a 32 character length string, while `password_hash()` is a minimum of 60.

Read the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

If and when you do decide to use `password_hash()` or the compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/, it is important to note that if your present password column's length is anything lower than 60, it will need to be changed to that (or higher). The manual suggests a length of 255.

You will need to ALTER your column's length and start over with a new hash in order for it to take effect. Otherwise, MySQL will fail silently.

Comment: Then again, it might be a good idea to make that like *"If and when you do decide to use password_hash() or the compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/"* ;-)

Comment: I don't mind, although technically we're only saying which function to use, not the package that provides it. ;) But more importantly, even PHP 5.4 is now EOL, so ...

Comment: Some may not be able to use `password_hash()` due to a PHP version they may be forced to use (one server I work on is restricted to a lower version, why(?), I have no idea, I have no control over it), so I have to use the compatibility pack and others may also be forced to use it. Either way, they both require the (password) column length be a minimum of 60.

Comment: Yea, I know that pain ... I think that you linked the compat package as a comment is sufficient, but feel free to update the answer. :)

Comment: Done. I added it just in case some don't bother reading comments ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

`md5` (or any other hashing algorithm - see a full list with `hash_algos()`) will hash something to a constant(same) thing every time, in other words:

```
'1234' ---md5---> '81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055'
'1234' ---md5---> '81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055'
'1234' ---md5---> '81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055'
'1234' ---md5---> '81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055'
...
```

but `password_hash($password, $algo)` will hash something to a new thing every single time, in other words:

```
'1234' ---password_hash---> '$2y$10$VXj5/N79aVolZQHJa.wdUub4C1uifXCNGRVKVUIYnsuRGs/wnXU/S'
'1234' ---password_hash---> '$2y$10$BjSPyCyZU2Rui5MtL5MLC.bkLGbUxf/f9NshALvTc39lhemoWZFC6'
'1234' ---password_hash---> '$2y$10$WXGX/6dCLbJN77MKNNVbCej9Fya2fQGvPjAMLuU3a6zGCDuBMisbm'
'1234' ---password_hash---> '$2y$10$sqkB2ZK7BanIHTRZIKUHi.TVdseZE.GSMghBhuT7mDC9GrjW9g6Ky'
```

so a hash_verify_kind_function() is needed just for hashes made by `password_hash()` since you can hash your string with md5 (or any) and just check it if they are both equal or not **which is very stupid work because in this scenario you didn't need to hash it first with md5! because actually md5 hashing is not using for password hashing (and so verifying)**